# C++ Dereferencing char-Pointer (image array) is very slow

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I have some trouble getting fast access to an unsigned character array.

I want to actually copy a BGRABGRA....BGRABGRA.... linewise coded image array to the OpenCV-version which uses three layers. The code below works fine but is really slow (around 0.5 seconds for a 640*480 image). I pointed out that the dereferencing operator * makes it slow. Do you have any plan how to fix this? (Hint: BYTE is an unsigned char)

```
// run thorugh all pixels and copy image data
for (int y = 0; y<imHeight; y++){
    BYTE* pLine= vrIm->mp_buffer + y * vrIm->m_pitch;
    for (int x = 0; x<imWidth; x++){
        BYTE* b= pLine++; // fast pointer operation
        BYTE* g= pLine++;
        BYTE* r= pLine++;
        BYTE* a= pLine++; // (alpha)
        BYTE bc = *b; // this is really slow!
        BYTE gc = *g; // this is really slow!
        BYTE rc = *r; // this is really slow!

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: how did you come to such conclusion? you have profiled it?

Comment: I save images at 50 fps... When I want to put them to jpgs I notice the delay...

Comment: Half a second to read a block of RAM 1.2MB in size gives a memory bandwidth of ~2.5MB/s. Surely something else must be going on.

Comment: What platform are you on?  How have you determined that the dereferencing operator is part of your problem?  (Pointing something out is not the same as establishing its truth.)  It isn't normally that slow.

Comment: Where are you copying the data **to**? It looks like bc, gc, and rc are not used anywhere. Also, why not just do `BYTE bc = *pLine++; BYTE gc = *pLine++; BYTE rc = *pLine++; BYTE ac = *pLine++;` (assuming you want to do something with `*a` in your original code.) I don't think it helps cache performance to be dereferencing four different pointers, even if those pointers are pointing to contiguous addresses.

Comment: You're not, by any chance, noticing this slowdown in DEBUG mode are you?

Comment: I just write the RGB values to the cv image.. But that is not the reason for delay. Maybe the data is in a bad point of memory of the system? I use WinXP with Visual Studio 2008... The images come from a camera's driver.

Comment: Yes Im in debug. Does this really affect this operations so dramatically?

Comment: @user587699: yes, a debug build can easily be an order of magnitude or more slower than a release build

Comment: @user: Yes. There are two build configurations for a reason...complaining about performance in **debug** builds is about as sensible as complaining your car isn't going fast when you never let it go higher than first gear.

Comment: Well,ok. I did release now (I needed to add some paths for the linker). But the speed is not changed :(

Comment: One hint: The memory pointer which the bytes lay is e.g. 16911880. Maybe this memory area makes it take more time copying? Hmm its really strange. If I try a loop on other char pointers it works fine and fast...

Comment: 16911880 is `0x01020E08` (for future reference, *always* report pointer values in hexadecimal) and that shouldn't be a special memory area.  I think we need to see the *complete* function that this is a fragment of, and if possible also an assembly dump of that function when compiled in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be - there is no way that is taking 0.5sec for a 640x480 unless you are doing this on a 8086.  Is there some other code you aren't showing? The destination memory doesn't currently go anywhere

ps take a look at cvCvtColor() it uses optimized SSE2/SIMD instructions to do this

Comment: Allright! I will try it. Its really just the * lines. If I comment them, it's fast as it should be (but without image of course). The delay even happens without involving OpenCV.

Comment: `cvCvtColor(rgba_image, rgb_image, CV_RGBA2RGB);`

Comment: @karlphillip - not quite, the OP wants to convert into a planar image (r,g,b as separate layers)

Answer (score 0):

What hardware is the memory you're reading located on? Perhaps that device has limited bandwidth to the memory it uses or just has slow RAM. If the memory is shared by many devices there may also be bottle necks on it's access. Try reading the entire screen(?) to local memory using memcpy(), performing your operations on it in local RAM, then writing it back using memcpy(). This will reduce the number of times you must negotiate access to it from 640*480 to 1.